# How do you list all photos uploaded by you and tagged with a certain person?

Tags: facebook

I can only get Graph Search to return the list of *all* photos I can see tagged with a certain person.  Ultimately, I'd like to delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried phwd's answer, but it also returned photos that weren't uploaded by me.

Typing the following returned only those photos that I uploaded and are tagged with a certain person:

> Photos that I uploaded and are tagged with [name of friend]